# If $f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ then $f$ is meromorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let , $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ for all $z\in \mathbb C$ such that $e^z\not=1$. Then  , which is(/are) correct ?

(A) $f$ is meromorphic.

(B) the only singularities of $f$ are poles.

(C) $f$ has infintely many poles on the imaginary axis.

(D) each pole of $f$ is simple.

**Attempt :**

Since $e^z\not=1$ so $f$ has no singularity. So , $f$ is analytic and so $f$ is meromorphic.

So only option (A) is correct. Am I correct? If wrong then where my mistake ?

I am very confused about the given data $e^z\not =1$.

Comment: No,$f$ is not analytic,for example $f$ has simple pole at $z=0$ All options are correct!

Comment: @ Arpit Kansal) How ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only possible singularities are the zeros of denominator, i.e., points s.t. $e^z = 1$:
$$z=\text{Log }1 = 0 + 2k\pi i,\ k\in\Bbb Z.$$
As the derivative of $z\mapsto e^z - 1$ is $z\mapsto e^z\ne 0$, all its zeros are simple an all the singularities of $f$ are simple poles.

Comment: So all options are correct right?

Comment: @Quintic, right.

Comment: @ Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla) But sir in question it is given that $e^z\not=1$. So how the function has singularities ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729, because the *definition* of singularity of a complex function.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_%28mathematics%29#Complex_analysis.

Comment: @Martin-Blas Perez Pinilla..what would u like to comment on the analyticity of $f(z)=1/z$ on $\mathbb C$\{0}?

Comment: @mathlover, is simply a quotient of analytic functions.

Comment: Is it analytic in the punctured plane?

Comment: @mathlover, yes. But *without* analytic primitive.

Comment: If ur answer is 'yes' then how is the $f(z)=1/e^z-1$ on the complex plane punctured at the points $z=2nπi$ different from this?

Comment: @mathlover, isn't different. $1/z$ has a pole at $z=0$.

Comment: This is the only point I am unable to absorb..Did u really mean that $f=1/z$ on $D=\mathbb C$ has a pole at $z=0€D$ and same is the answer for $f=1/z$ on $D=\mathbb C$\{0}?

Comment: @mathlover, from the definition of singularity (see the link in a previous comment): "Suppose $U$ is an open subset of the complex numbers $\Bbb C$, and the point a is an element of $U$, and $f$ is a complex differentiable function defined on some neighborhood around $a$, excluding $a$: $U\setminus \{a\}$..."

Comment: Should not be $z\mapsto e^z\ne 0$ instead of $z\mapsto e^z\ne 1$ ?

Comment: @Isa, yes. Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*$Hint:$* Here $f(z)=1/(e^z-1)$ for $z$ in set of all complex numbers

$A=\mathbb C$-{$2nπi:n€Z$}.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Don't use the comments as chat, please.

Answer (score 0):

Here $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}$

The poles of this function can be find by putting $e^z-1=0\implies e^z=1=e^{2n\pi i}\implies z=2n\pi i$, $n \in \mathbb Z$

Now using L'Hospital rule $$\lim_{z  \to  2n \pi i}(z-2n\pi i)f(z)=\lim_{z  \to  2n \pi i} \frac{1}{e^z}=1 \neq 0$$ so $f(z)$ has simple pole at $z=2n\pi i$. **(option $D$ is true)**

Since only at poles $f(z)$ is not analytic, so only singularities of $f(z)$ are poles. **(option $B$ is true)**

Given function $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ is everywhere analytic except at poles.

Again all poles (which are infinitely many) are on the imaginary axis. **(option $C$ is true)**

Hence $f(z)$ is meromorphic. **(option $A$ is true)**

---

> A **meromorphic function** is a single valued function that is analytic in all but possibly a discrete subset of its domain and at these singularities it must go to infinity like polynomial. i.e., $$f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$$ wheer $g(z)$ and $h(z)$ are analytic with $h(z)\neq 0$

---

> A **simple pole** of an analytic function $f(z)$ is a pole of order one. That is, $(z-z_0)f(z)$ is an analytic function at the pole $z=z_0$.
>
> In other word, for $f(z)$ has pole at  $z=z_1 \in \mathbb C$, $$\lim_{z \to z_1} f(z)= \infty$$
>
> For simple pole at $z=z_1 \in \mathbb C$, $$\lim_{z \to z_1} (z-z_1)f(z) \qquad \text{is finite.}$$