# Is $f$ a meromorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{e^z-1}$ such that $e^z\neq 1$. Is $f$ a meromorphic function?

Since the singularities of $f$ are only the poles ,hence $f$ is a meromorphic function.

Is the following justification enough?

Comment: You must add that the set of singularities of $f$ is discrete. $f$ is said to be meromorphic on $U$ if there exists $S\subset U$ a discrete set such that $f$ is holomorphic on $U\setminus S$ and $f$ admits a non essential singularity at each point of $S$.

Comment: then is the fact that $f$ is meromorphic true? @C.Falcon

Comment: $f$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, since $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus 2i\pi\mathbb{Z}$ and $2i\pi\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{C}$ is discrete and $f$ admits a pole of order one, hence a non-essential singularity at each point of $2i\pi\mathbb{Z}$. Also, possible duplicate of: [If $f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ then $f$ is meromorphic.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585738/if-fz-frac1ez-1-then-f-is-meromorphic).

Comment: @Falcon it would be probably informative for future readers if you could give some hint on an example with non-discrete singularities.

Comment: @GyroGearloose The sole example I can come with is: $$f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}.$$ $f$ is not meromorphic on the whole plane since $0$ is an accumulation point of poles.

Comment: A meromorphic function is locally either by definition or equivalently a quotient of holomorphic functions, which is true in this case.